# How to display java.time.LocalDate (Java 8) in Spring MVC 4 JSP

Tags: java, datetime, jsp

I am trying to use some new features from Java 8. java.time.LocalDate seems a fantastic solution for all java date/time related problem.

```
<input id="placemententity_placementFinishDate"
    name="placementFinishDate" type="text"
    value="<fmt:formatDate value="${placemententity.placementFinishDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"/>"
```

I just retrieved a LocalDate type of field from EJB and send it to JSP to display.

But somehow I never make it display properly. Does any one have experience? Please share with me.

**Edit**

This is the code was used to display and input value in my table:

```
<td>
    <input id="placemententity_placementFinishDate" name="placementFinishDate" type="text"
    value="<fmt:formatDate value="${placemententity.placementFinishDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"/>" style="width: 300px;" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
    elementId : "placemententity_placementFinishDate",widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",widgetAttrs : {
    promptMessage: "<fmt:message key="navigation.dateTime.title"/>"}})); </script>
</td>
```

Seems Spring initbind not bind java.time.LocalDate to any other data type.

```
 error code shows, can't assign a java.util.Date to java.time.LocaLdate.
```

Seems Spring MVC defined that field as java.util.Date, but modelAttrbute field is java.time.LocalDate. so field type mis-matched.

Comment: This class does not store or represent a time, so your pattern is going to fail anyway.

Comment: "But somehow I never make it display properly" doesn't tell us anything about what you're actually seeing or what you expected to see.

Comment: You need a `LocalDateTime` instance.